# shapefiles for New York City Airports

Tags: shapefile, r

Where can I get shapefiles for New York City Airports?

I want to check if certain latitude longitude points are within the airports, so if I have a shapefile, I can use R to check whether or not my points are found with in the airports.

Or it is possible to create my own shapefiles using R?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question under our focussed Q&A format.  If you seek open data I think the best place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

The [National Transportation Atlas](https://www.rita.dot.gov/bts/sites/rita.dot.gov.bts/files/publications/national_transportation_atlas_database/2012/index.html) is a rich source, and it offers an airports shapefile. It's for the entire country, but you can easily filter out the airports that you are interested in.

The link above is (most likely) point files, so you won't be able to do a within query.

Comment: You could use the points to select the land parcel it falls within.. it may not be tarmac area but (theoretically) the airport *owns* the whole land parcel and anything that falls within the parcel (or parcels) that the airport sits on could be considered *within the airport*. Note an airport may overlap many land parcels so it would be a good idea to check each point and manually select the parcels with imagery (base map) active.